# How can I disable php scripts on a specific subdir of my website on IIS7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, wordpress

How can I disable php scripts on a specific subdir of my website using IIS7?

I have a wordpress blog and I want to disable php on the "uploads" dir.

Answer (score 3):

You have quite a few options here. All code examples (one for each approach) need to be placed in **web.config** file in your **"uploads"** folder (in case if you do not know this).

1) **Remove handler** that is responsible for processing *.php files (in IIS Manager it is "Handler Mappings"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP 5" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Cons:

- You need to know the handler name
- Handler name can be changed in a future (admin may change to handle PHP in a different way etc)

2) Using **Request Filtering** module disable all requests to files with `.php` extension -- server will send 404.7 error to the client. This module is bundled with IIS 7.5, but for IIS 7.0 you may need to download and install [Administration Pack](http://www.iis.net/download/AdministrationPack).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".php" allowed="false" />
                </fileExtensions>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you have more than one extension for PHP you will need to list them as well (e.g. `.phtml`, `.php5` etc).

3) Using **URL Rewrite module** create a rule to **Abort** such request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Abort PHP" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*\.php$" />
                    <action type="AbortRequest" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- IIS 7.0 has no URL Rewrite module bundled while IIS 7.5 has v1.1. Unfortunately I have no v1.1 of this extension installed -- only v2 and cannot check/guarantee that this will work in v1.1. In any case -- I recommend to download and install version 2 of [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite).
- You will need to extend this rule to also catch other file extensions that may be processed by PHP on your setup (e.g. `.phtml`, `.php5` etc).

4) Using **URL Rewrite module** create a rule to **respond with custom error** instead of processing such request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Disable PHP" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*\.php$" />
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="No PHP here" statusDescription="Sorry mate" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

5) Using **URL Rewrite module** create a rule to **redirect to your own error page** for all of such requests.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Show Our Error Page for PPHP files" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*\.php$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/404.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The above rule will internally redirect (rewrite) such requests to a `404.php` file in the website root folder (e.g. `http://www.example.com/404.php`)

---

Use #2 if possible -- it will be executed before URL Rewrite step which will be beneficial on very busy server.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a little old, but I personally subscribe to the "Write + Execute = BAD" school of thought, and therefore a upload folder should never execute. With this in mind, any handler beyond the static file handler could be considered a security risk.

To remove all but the static file handler (regardless of what the other handlers are called) (all the benefits of #1 in the above, but without the Cons):

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
       <clear />
        <add 
            name="StaticFile" 
            path="*" verb="*" 
            modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" 
            resourceType="Either" 
            requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```